# User Agent "iOS/14.4 (18D52) dataaccessd/1.0" calls old calendar links

Tags: ios, user-agent

I keep on getting calls to my dynamic calendar files, which are more than a year outdated, all with the same user agent

```
iOS/14.4 (18D52) dataaccessd/1.0
```

Does anybody have an idea, where this is coming from?

Comment: I'm getting the same log entries showing up constantly. No clue where they are coming from.

`"iOS/14.6 (18F72) dataaccessd/1.0"


"iOS/15.1.1 (19B81) dataaccessd/1.0"


"iOS/15.1 (19B74) dataaccessd/1.0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is comming from Calendar app on iPhone if user subscribes to calendar. Calendar app periodically checks if there is any updates so that's why you are getting constant requests.